# Query in polymorphic association - Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, polymorphic-associations

I would like to made a query on a polymorphic association :

```
@pois = Poi.where(poitable: Sleep.where(track_id: @track.id))
```

Fine, there works... and I would like add a second argument :

```
@pois = Poi.where(poitable: Sleep.where(track_id: @track.id)).or.where(poitable: Town.where(track_id: @track.id))
```

Now, I get an error :  "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)"

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The or method takes an argument that's another ActiveRecord query

So the syntax would be :

```
Poi.where(poitable: Sleep.where(track_id: @track.id)).or(Poi.where(poitable: Town.where(track_id: @track.id)))
```